# Add pin(not marker) to google map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How to add a pin(not a marker)to the google map in android?
I know how to add a marker, something like this:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()))
                .title(getString(R.string.start_location_marker)));
```

But I want a pin, not a marker.
A pin looks like this:
[pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVwQT.png)

A marker looks like this:
[marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WND5X.png)

Comment: add this line to marker `.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your pin image to marker it is called custom marker

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(21.4225, 39.8262);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Mecca").icon(icon)).showInfoWindow();
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
}
```